# Install Lisp Interpreter in Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, software-installation, lisp

I convinced myself to learn Lisp. I'd like to know of a way to install a Lisp Interpreter on Debian(Jessie). I was reading about clisp but is not in the repositories of Debian.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SBCL is included in Debian too, and it's a really popular Common Lisp implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this command :

```
sudo apt-get install sbcl
```

Next, we set up *Quicklisp*, the package manager. This is similarly:

```
$ curl -o /tmp/ql.lisp http://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp

$ sbcl --no-sysinit --no-userinit --load /tmp/ql.lisp \
   --eval '(quicklisp-quickstart:install :path ".quicklisp")' \
   --quit
```

Answer (score 0):

The [GNU clisp](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/) is only available for debian Buster and Sid through `apt`.

For debian Stretch and Jessie the GNU clisp can be installed through [`guix` package manager](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/manual/en/html_node/Binary-Installation.html).

To install clisp:

```
$ guix package -i clisp
```

Sample output from debian Stretch:

```
clisp --version
GNU CLISP 2.49.60 (2017-06-25) (built 2208985201) (memory 3734909887)
Software: GNU C 5.5.0
```